# Why is Fixnum#size equal to 8?

Tags: ruby

Why does `nil.to_i.size` return `8`?

Comment: Dave, `nil.to_i #=> 0` and `0.class #=> Fixnum` (of course).  So you can answer own question by just reading the docs for [Fixnum#size](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-size).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nil.to_i` returns 0.  And the `size` method in `Fixnum` returns the number of bytes in the machine representation of a `Fixnum`.

Comment: so thats why 200000000.size stil equals 8? Thanks

Comment: Correct.  Any Fixnum on a given machine should return the same value.  Probably 8 just about anywhere nowadays.